# speed of magento 2 very slow suddenly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin

In my **local host** magento 2 running very fast but due to some reason i delete some files and module and then its speed becomes very poor and it takes approx 3 or 4 minutes loading its home page.

Comment: Which files have you deleted, what are you overwriting? Tell us more...

Comment: some modules file and plugins

Comment: It is always best to disable a module, run setup:upgrade and then delete the module otherwise a lot of redundant broken links/connections may remain.

Comment: now what will i do?

Comment: Have you ran setup:upgrade, s:d:c, s:s:d? if not run them in that order perhaps it may help. 1) bin/magento setup:upgrade, bin/magento s:d:c, bin/magento s:s:d 
Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you suddenly find that your Magento is massively slow after installing or updating a module, it might be this known bug where composer update turns off all your cache!

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17634

I know that this happens to me about once or twice a month. I now know to immediately go into command line and run `php bin/magento cache:status` and I will see that all my cache is set to 0. Then I run `php bin/magento cache:enable` and go on with my day.